# Is it possible to disable/hide the controls from gmaps using Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter

I'm trying to make a map with some markers using Jupyter Notebook(Python Kernel). First i create the gmaps.figure() and here goes my question, the map renders street view button, zoom button, etc. I'd like to disable this buttons, but i don't know how. I've found many soluctions using JS or other languages, but i don't know how to do this in Jupyter. Does anyone know if it's possible? If yes, how can i do?

I tried to change it throught layout, but i wasn't possible. Even when i create the figure.

```
gmaps.configure(api_key=MapToken)
TipoMapa = 'ROADMAP'
GeoBra = (-15.7745457,-48.3575684)
ZoomInicial = 5
MapLayout = {
    'widht': '900px',
    'height': '700px'
}
fig = gmaps.figure(
    map_type=TipoMapa, 
    center=GeoBra, 
    zoom_level=ZoomInicial,     
    mouse_handling='GREEDY',
    layout=MapLayout
)
fig
```

I want the render without all those controls(zoom, street view, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript this is achieved with `disableDefaultUI: true`. Take a look at this Google [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI).

From looking at the jupyter-gmaps [API documentation](https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) though, this is not a supported parameter at the moment. So you may want to file a FR or even submit a PR yourself.

Hope this helps.